# How do I only add complete items to this list

Tags: angularjs

I'm using an input field to accept comma-separated values then dynamically generating list items for each comma-separated value.  However, I don't want items added to the list until they have a comma after them.  For example, if I enter "Dog, Cat, Fish" in the input field, I don't want the following as I'm typing "Cat"

- Dog
- Ca

I want "Cat" to be added only once I've put a comma after it to indicate it is a complete entry.

Here's the code I'm using to achieve this.

```
      <input ng-list ng-model="labels" placeholder="Enter labels">
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li ng-repeat="label in labels track by $index">
          {{ label }}
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

[Link to running example](http://plnkr.co/edit/Vyr80QA7UVC5uxJggcnc?p=info)

What's the angular way to achieve this?

Comment: Why not just slice the last item off the list after spliting?

Comment: Provide an example in code and you got yourself 25 points ;o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this would be to use custom filters to filter the ng-repeat items instead of relying on the ng-list directive.

See the associated [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/J1Q5RmvWzjQoVLZK5QZv?p=preview) of the code below.

**HTML**

```
<input ng-model="labels" placeholder="Enter labels" />
<div>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="label in labels | completeList">
          {{ label }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
filter('completeList', function() {
  return function(items) {
    var list = [];
    if(items) {
      list = items.split(',');
      var last = list[list.length - 1];
      if(items.charAt(items.length - 1) != ',' || last.length === 0)
        list.pop();
    }
    return list;
  };
});
```